# Check IP address input and then export to Out-GridView

Tags: powershell

How can I combine this code to check IP address and list the result into Gridview?

```
function Test-IP
{
   param
   (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
      [ValidateScript({ $_ -match [IPAddress]$_ })]
      [String]$ip
      
   )
   
   $ip
   Write-Host "$($ip) is resolved to $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostbyAddress($($IP)))"
}

while (!Test-IP -ip "$($Input)")
{
   $input = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your IP address'
}

$zones = Get-DnsServerZone - Server PRDDNS05-VM | Where-Object { !$_.IsReverseLookupZone -and $_.ZoneType -eq 'Primary' }
$output = foreach ($zone in $zones)
{
   Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $zone.ZoneName |
   Where { $_.RecordData.Ipv4Address.IPAddressToString -contains $Input } |
   Select IPV4Address, HostName, RecordType, Type, RecordData, Timestamp, TimeToLive, @{ n = 'Zone'; e = { $zone.ZoneName } }
}
$output | Out-GridView
```

The script above is used to dump all DNS entries which contain specific IP address input by the user.

Comment: `$input` is an automatic variable in Powershell. You shouldn’t redefine it as a variable that you introduce. Renaming it will have better results.

Comment: Yes, you're right man :-) thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of an odd construct, as I am not sure why you are using that function, the way you are. Meaning, running a function with a required mandatory param and then a check whether to determine if one was entered and if not send a Read-host, until the user does. Mandatory means, mandatory. Don't continue unless something is entered.

If you are checking just to make sure the user enters a proper IPA, then check for that in the validate param. Meaning only allow an IPA format.

Also, this...

```
Get-DnsServerZone - Server PRDDNS05-VM
```

... is not valid syntax. There is no parameter called -Server for that cmdlet. There is only ...

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-DnsServerZone).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-DnsServerZone).Parameters.Keys
# Results
<#
Name
ComputerName
VirtualizationInstance
CimSession
ThrottleLimit
AsJob
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
#>
Get-help -Name Get-DnsServerZone -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-DnsServerZone -Full
Get-help -Name Get-DnsServerZone -Online
```

...and there are never spaces between the dash and the ParameterName. I assume that was just a typo in the post but just say'in.

Taking this one step at a time, just ask for the basics.

```
function Test-IPaddress
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,Position = 0)]
                  [ValidateScript({$_ -match [IPAddress]$_ })]
                  [string]$IPAddress
    )

    Process{[ipaddress]$IPAddress}
}

Try
{
    $IPAddress = $((Test-IPaddress -IPAddress (Read-Host -Prompt 'Input a valid IP address')).IPAddressToString)
    Out-GridView -InputObject $IPAddress -Title "IPAddress details for $IPAddress"
}
Catch 
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Drawing,
                            PresentationCore,
                            PresentationFramework,
                            System.Windows.Forms,
                            microsoft.VisualBasic
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Warning message for $IPAddress`n 
    $($PSItem.Exception.Message)" , 'Error', 'OK', 'Error')
}
```

Once we know that very basic call works and outputs to OGV as expected, you can add your other code in the try block and format that to fit OGV as well.

***Update as per my comment***

```
db-ip.com/all/113.67.32 

Test-Connection -ComputerName db-ip.com | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results
<#
Source Destination IPV4Address IPV6Address Bytes Time(ms)
------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----- --------
L...   db-ip.com   104.26.5.15             32    15      
L...   db-ip.com   104.26.5.15             32    12      
L...   db-ip.com   104.26.5.15             32    12      
L...   db-ip.com   104.26.5.15             32    11 
#>


Test-Connection -ComputerName 104.26.5.15 | Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Source Destination IPV4Address IPV6Address Bytes Time(ms)
------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----- --------
L...   104.26.5.15                         32    15      
L...   104.26.5.15                         32    14      
L...   104.26.5.15                         32    15      
L...   104.26.5.15                         32    13
#>

Test-Connection -ComputerName 113.67.32.221 | Format-Table -AutoSize
$Error[0] | Format-List -Force
# Results
<#
writeErrorStream      : True
Exception             : System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException: Testing connection to computer '113.67.32.221' failed: Error due to lack of 
                        resources ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Error due to lack of resources
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
TargetObject          : 113.67.32.221
CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (113.67.32.221:String) [Test-Connection], PingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1, 0}
PSMessageDetails      : 
#>

Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 113.67.32.221 -TraceRoute
# Results
<#
WARNING: Ping to 113.67.32.221 failed with status: TimedOut
WARNING: Trace route to destination 113.67.32.221 did not complete. Trace terminated :: 0.0.0.0


ComputerName           : 113.67.32.221
RemoteAddress          : 113.67.32.221
...
PingSucceeded          : False
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
...
#>



Ping 113.67.32.221
# Results
<#
Pinging 113.67.32.221 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
...

Ping statistics for 113.67.32.221:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
#>

tracert 113.67.32.221
# Results
<#
Tracing route to 113.67.32.221 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     1 ms     1 ms     2 ms  ...
  2    24 ms    22 ms   122 ms  ... 
  3    14 ms    41 ms    19 ms  ...
...
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
#>


telnet 113.67.32.221
# Results
<#
Connecting To 113.67.32.221...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: 
Connect failed
#>

telnet 113.67.32.221 80
# Results
<#
Connecting To 113.67.32.221...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: 
Connect failed
#>
```

Comment: thank you for the response. However, when I enter the public IP address, I got this error:
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Warning message for 113.67.32.221
 

    Exception calling "GetHostByAddress" with "1" argument(s): "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: it is a valid Public IP address: https://db-ip.com/all/113.67.32

Comment: It may be a legit IPA string but that IPA does not resolve using the basic PowerShell cmdlets (or even good ol' DOS stuff), so, it's not going to resolve with any other code methods. See my update for validation. Because it's a valid IPA, the OGV will popup. If you've added other code, that that will fail as noted in the update.

Comment: That's great. Many thanks, man for the update and the explanation. It works great.

Comment: No worries. Glad it all worked out for you. My default dev approach is always to do the absolute minimum code (starting with only using the cmdlets/exe's, etc., with no fancy/creative stuff (meaning raw data pulls) and test to make sure you can get what you want before moving on. Once I validate each piece/segment/block, then I pull them together in a script, modules, etc. It just decreases headaches and unneeded hair pulling (of which I have none anymore   ;-})

Comment: ;-) lol, I appreciate that you've shared all the thought process on your answer above. it is easy to follow.